# Docker can't connect from a spring boot container to a mysql container

Tags: spring-boot, docker

i'm trying to connect 2 docker instances a simple spring boot app container and a mysql container but i get the following error message

`java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)`

here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3' 

services: 
  docker-mysql: 
    restart: always 
    container_name: docker-mysql 
    image: mysql 
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-import:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: books_db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - book-mysql-network
    healthcheck:
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=root --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      interval: 2s
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
  web-service:
      build:
        context: ./book-service
      ports:
        - "8099:8099"
      networks:
        - book-mysql-network
      depends_on:
        - docker-mysql

networks:
  book-mysql-network:
    driver: bridge
```

and application.properties file

```
server.port=8099

spring.application.name=book-service
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/books_db?characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Comment: does your `web-service` container wait for MySQL server to be available for connection? what happen if after the error you restart `web-service` container?

Comment: @x80486 Spring app is running on a container, thus there is no service running on `localhost:3306`(spring container itself). Please remove you comment to avoid confusing questioner.

Comment: @ROOT im not sure, but i think it does because the mysql container logs  `MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20' ` before spring boot container starts, plus i've tried to run mysql container with docker run command andwait untill it starts successfully then run the spring boot container but still the same error.

Comment: @ROOT i did restart the web-service container, the container is up but the logs shows the same error, i also did ping the docker-mysql with `docker exec -i 04d28d8f4524 bash "ping docker-mysql` and the docker-mysql is reachable.

Comment: @ahmed not experienced in `spring boot`, but shouldn't the connection be `mysql://root:root@docker-mysql:3306/books_db?characterEncoding=utf-8` maybe you have to provide the username and password to the connection string/URL.